# How to write an SQL function to cut down on code repetition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to run an SQL function for multiple countries

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a function where I can just input the country name and get a table for each. Here's my query for Germany

```
SELECT customer.id,
       product_purchased,
       country
FROM sales_tables
WHERE country = 'Germany'
```

So instead of changing each country in the code, can I do something like this

```
FUNCTION products_purchased_byCountry($1):
    SELECT customer.id,
           product_purchased,
           country
    FROM sales_tables
    WHERE country = '$1'
```

Then just call this function with the following

```
products_purchased_byCountry(Germany)
products_purchased_byCountry(France)
products_purchased_byCountry(UK)
```

Or maybe to run such a function I have to do it through R, or Python?

Comment: You are using MS SQL Server?

Comment: The title of problem should be more clarify, and that will help others to know the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a stored procedure and set @country as a variable.

```
Create procedure products_purchased_byCountry

@country varchar(100)

AS BEGIN

SELECT customer.id,
       product_purchased,
       country
FROM sales_tables
WHERE country = @country

END
```

Then call it like this

```
EXEC products_purchased_byCountry 
@country = 'Germany'
```

Comment: I would recommend against a stored procedure as you can't readily use this in another query.

Comment: Good point! A function would be easier to call in another query, depends what the OP wants to use it for.

Comment: No problem! @cget

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using Microsoft SQL Server (2005 or better)...

You can create a stored procedure that accepts your country parameter and returns a tabular record set (as mentioned in another answer here).

You could also create a “User Defined Table Function” (UDF). The nice thing about table UDF’s is that you can call them just like a table or a view. You can perform table joins against them (unlike stored procedures).

Here is an example table UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfMyFunc( @country VARCHAR(50) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE country_name = @country
```

You can do more complex things (multi-statement UDF) if you add a BEGIN after the AS, and an END after everything else... so long as your final statement is the RETURN (result set).

I’ve often found that when calling a UDF you have to include the schema name prefix (dbo Iin this case).

```
SELECT cou.col1, cou.col2, cou.col3
FROM dbo.udfMyFunc(‘France’) AS cou
```

Have fun with this...

Answer (score 2):

the exact syntax will depend on the dialect of SQL you're using, but this should generally be possible. In PostgreSQL, for example, this concept is called a [User Defined Function (UDF)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/xfunc-sql.html).

The syntax would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase (
  id                   varchar,
  product_purchased    varchar,
  country              varchar
);

CREATE FUNCTION products_purchased_byCountry(varchar) RETURNS purchase AS $$
  SELECT customer.id,
       product_purchased,
       country
  FROM sales_tables
  WHERE country = '$1'
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT country('Germany') AS answer;
```

However, generalizing basic queries like this would quickly get cumbersome - UDFs are best used for highly reusable, more complex queries. In this case, you'll probably want to format in your variable in the language you're using to wrap your SQL, such as Python or Javascript, and then pass the complete query string into SQL as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention you want to do this through R or python, there are other options than SQL stored procedures.  In R, the `DBI` package can be used to connect to a database, and the `dbGetquery` function pulls data from a query.  You can write sql injection safe queries with the `param` argument.  Here is a MWE:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE hp > :hp", param=list(hp=100))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a stored procedure (and probably a function as well)

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE products_purchased_byCountry
      @country varchar(50)
  AS

      SELECT [customer.id],
             product_purchased,
          country
      FROM sales_table
      WHERE country = @country
```

then call that with

products_purchased_byCountry 'Germany'

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server use a [Table valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-use-table-valued-user-defined-functions).

As an answer to the other posts, you use a Procedure when you just want to do something without a return, eg insert into xxx
And a function when you want something to be returned to the calling script/procedure.